# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta del tipo LIKE en Firebase?

Tags: firebase, mongodb

En estos momentos infortunadamente para mi aplicación que se encuentra en producción ando usando dos bases de datos, una en **MongoDB** y otra en **Firebase**. En **Mongo** tengo los datos de las *Empresas* que han descargado la *app* ya que en algún momento tendría que hacer un buscador de empresas, traer todo de `schemaCompanies` donde `nameCompany` tenga parecido a `$_value`. Es la consulta que hace en *Mongo* para hacer funcionar el buscador, eso sumado a otros campos del documento.

Lo que quiero hacer es pasar completamente a *Firebase* pero no puedo hacerlo si no logro solucionar consultas del tipo `LIKE`.

¿Cómo se soluciona esto?

**Consulta en Mongo:**

```
await CompanySchema.find({
      $or: [
        { Actividad: { $regex: value, $options: "i" } },
        { name: { $regex: value, $options: "i" } },
        { NIT: { $regex: value, $options: "i" } },
        { Site: { $regex: value, $options: "i" } }]
    }, { admin: false, TitlePage: false, PortadaURL: false });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se pueden hacer consultas tipo LIKE por el momento en Firebase ya que no existe el operador, podes ver las limitaciones en el siguiente link

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Lo que podes hacer, es usar `orderBy` (o `orderByChild`) acompañado del valor de inicio y fin de tu query, que funcionaria como un Like

Ejemplo de una referencia donde vas a la coleccion usuario, ordenas por nombre el cual empieze en ese mismo con `startAt(name)`

### Firestore

```
ref.collection('usuario').orderBy('nombre').startAt(nombre).endAt(nombre+'\uf8ff')
```

### Realtime

```
ref.child('usuario').orderByChild('nombre').startAt(nombre).endAt(nombre+'\uf8ff')
```

El caracter **\uf8ff** es usado en la query como un rango Unicode para que la query pueda obtener todos los valores que empiezan con **nombre**

De esta manera, buscando por ejemplo "Gas" podría obtener los registros que tienen "Gaston, Gast, Gasto" como valor en la propiedad **nombre** de la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes concatenar el valor buscado con un par de `.*`

```
await CompanySchema.find({
      $or: [
        { Actividad: { $regex: `.*${ value }.*`, $options: "i" } },
        { name: { $regex: `.*${ value }.*`, $options: "i" } },
        { NIT: { $regex: `.*${ value }.*`, $options: "i" } },
        { Site: { $regex: `.*${ value }.*`, $options: "i" } }]
    }, { admin: false, TitlePage: false, PortadaURL: false });
```

Eso debería resolver el problema

Comment: En mi pregunta, en el segundo párrafo denoto: Lo que quiero hacer es pasar completamente a Firebase pero no puedo hacerlo si no logro solucionar consultas del tipo LIKE, alguien tiene alguna duda sobre como podría solucionarlo?. la idea es hacer consultas LIKE en firebase